# How to loop through directory and delete files matching array of filenames in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to delete files that begin with the array values and end with "_1.txt", from this given directory. I have this so far, which deletes the files successfully, but it throws an error every time, "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tom_1.txt'". I think the loop is not ending somehow, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
import os
directory = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/'
names = np.array(['tom','jen','bob'])
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    for name in names:
        os.remove(f'{name}_1.txt')
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the actual file list (`filename`) is not used anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

`os.scandir` only returns the file names.  You have to add the path:

```
        os.remove( f'{directory}{name}_1.txt' )
```

However, unless every name exists, that might still fail.  You might consider:

```
        name = f'{directory}{name}_1.txt'
        if os.path.isfile(name):
            os.remove(name)
```

I didn't even notice you aren't using the result of `os.scandir`.  You can remove that outer loop and this will still work.